# C++ Pass a new instance of vector

Tags: c++, arrays, arguments

I am working on my midterm for a class. I need to initialize a a constant array of objects that take a vector as constructor args. Basically, I want to do something similar to the following Java code:

```
final Pizza[] standardMenu = {
    new Pizza(Arrays.asList(new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3))),
    new Pizza(Arrays.asList(new Integer(4), new Integer(5), new Integer(6)))};
```

Except instead of Integer instances I would pass Ingredient instances. Is there a way to do something like that in C++? Both my book and a quick google search did not yield any good results.

The code Im looking at right now (C++):

```
Ingredient standardIngredients[8] = {Ingredient("American Cheese", "Cheese that comes from America", 1.0), Ingredient("Swiss Cheese", "Cheese that is Swiss", 1.0),
                    Ingredient("Peperoni", "Does it need a description?", 2.0), Ingredient("Ground Beef", "Ground up beef", 3.0),
                    Ingredient("Onion", "Its a vegetable", 0.5), Ingredient("Black Olives", "Olives that possess the color of blackness", 0.5),
                    Ingredient("Jalapenios", "Spicy things", 0.5), Ingredient("Pickles", "Just because I can", 0.5)};
Pizza standardMenu[1] = {Pizza({standardIngredients[0], standardIngredients[1]}, "A string", 7.8)};
```

Comment: Show us what you tried please.

Comment: `Pizza standardMenu[2] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};` + `std::make_unique`?

Comment: You'd have gotten at least 3 answers by now if you posted some code you tried...

Comment: Added my current C++ code

Comment: What's the trailing double in your Ingredient ?

Comment: something that would be the price of that ingredient, used for calculating price of the pizza later. Basically just a parameter that is stored in the instance for the time being EDIT: its a constructor that takes (string, string, float) values

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this help:

```
typedef vector<string> Pizza; 
auto menu = vector<Pizza>{ Pizza{ "chorizo", "tomato", "pepperoni" }, 
                           Pizza{ "Ananas", "Ham" } };
```

or if you prefer your menu as an array:

```
Pizza menu[] = { Pizza{ "chorizo", "tomato", "pepperoni" }, Pizza{ "Ananas", "Ham" } };
```

Of course this is a first step, because in this model, the Pizza is only the summ of its parts.  It would be better to have a dedicated class if you'd want to add more infos, like the price of the pizza, the calories, etc...

**Edit:**

Following your additional information, I propose the following classes:

```
class Ingredient {
    string name;
    string description;
    double price;
public:
    Ingredient(string n, string d, double p) : name(n), description(d), price(p) {}
};
class Pizza {
    vector<Ingredient> ingredients; 
    string name; 
    double price; 
public:
    Pizza(vector<Ingredient>i, string n, double p) : ingredients(i), name(n), price(p) {}
};
```

Your initialisations will work with that.

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I am doing. Only difference is I am going to keep ingredients stored as ints, since there is an immutable list of them.

Comment: The only thing I cannot figure out with your solution, as well as with many others - is why do I keep getting Type name not allowed error when I try to instantiate the menu array?

Comment: I could compile it without errors as far as I remember.  Are you using gcc ?  Have you set the option -std=c++11  ?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of compiler I am using. Ive only been playing with C++ for just under a week. C++ version is 11, though if that helps. And where or how would I set this -std=c++11 option?

Comment: If you use Visual Studio you compile automatically in C++11.  But with gcc you have to tell it to the compiler when you call it from the command line: `g++ -std=c++11 source.cpp` .  Or do you use an online tool ?

Comment: Yes, I use Visual Studio, and I use the built in functionality to compile and run my code. I just tried using the g++ -std=c++11 source.cpp from the directory my sourcefile is in, and got a g++ is not a recognized command message. I guess itd be safe to say I dont have gcc?

Comment: Ok !  With MSVC ou do not need this option.  However, not all the version support all C++11 features.  Initializer lists for examples are only in VIsual Studio 2013 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).  Which is your version ?

Comment: Ah, ok, I think this must be the issue then. I have to use Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a constructor for Pizza that takes a vector of Ingredient as an argument, or define an initializer_list for Pizza to save a bit of typing.

Also note the use of std::array. You shouldn't C-style arrays anymore for the most part, STL containers do nice things like remember their size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

class Ingredient {};
class Pizza {
public:
    Pizza(initializer_list<Ingredient> l) : ing{l} {}
    Pizza(vector<Ingredient> l) : ing{l} {}
private:
    vector<Ingredient> ing;
};

int main()
{
    const array<Pizza, 3> pizzas1 {
        Pizza{Ingredient{}, Ingredient{}, Ingredient{}},
        Pizza{Ingredient{}, Ingredient{}, Ingredient{}},
        Pizza{Ingredient{}, Ingredient{}, Ingredient{}}
    };

    const array<Pizza, 3> pizzas2 {
        Pizza{vector<Ingredient>{Ingredient{}}},
        Pizza{vector<Ingredient>{Ingredient{}}},
        Pizza{vector<Ingredient>{Ingredient{}}}
    };

}
```

Comment: If `Pizza` takes an `initializer_list`, (and probably an iterator pair) you can save a lot of typing.  Even as it is, a lot of what you have there is redundant.

Comment: it appears a constructor is never called in your code? or am I wrong?

Comment: @user1219387 Constructors are called.

Comment: @user1219387 It's using uniform initialization: http://mbevin.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/uniform-initialization/

Comment: @user1219387 and using member initialization list to construct the private member: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Ah. Ok that makes much more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
class Pizza
{
private:
    std::vector<int> m_members;
public:
    Pizza(std::vector<int> &members) : m_members(members)
    {

    }
};

const Pizza pizzaArray[] = { Pizza(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}),
                             Pizza(std::vector<int>{4, 5, 6}), };
```

Comment: What is the : m_members(members) part in your constructor? Can you give a bit of an explanation or a link to where that is documented?

Comment: It is the same as "m_members = members".

Comment: @armanali no, its not the same, and thats exactly the point of initialization lists. Explain the difference to the OP

Comment: @Manu343726, I think my explanation will suffice. Feel free to add more explanation if you think I am missing something.